# Recover a corrupt directory?

Tags: data-recovery, ntfs, data-corruption

I do some photography, and I was trying to copy all of my recent raws (.NEF files, since I use a Nikon camera) from my SD card to an HDD that I have mounted (formatted in NTFS) using the basic copy/paste function in Nautilus. During the file transfer, my system crashed for some unknown reason (this has been happening occasionally recently, although I don't believe the mounted HDD is at fault). When the system rebooted, I attempted to continue the file transfer, but it kept running into an error. I then browsed to the destination folder in Nautilus, and it simply said "Folder is Empty." Concerned, I went to the command line and received this output from `ls`:

```
username@localhost:/path_to_main_folder/destination_directory$ ls
ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error
```

Switching to the main folder, I got this output from `ls -l`:

```
username@localhost:/path_to_main_folder$ ll | grep destination_directory
drwxrwxrwx 1 username username   1036288 Apr 14 15:27 destination_directory/
```

So, strangely, `ls` sees that the destination directory must have sizeable contents, but can't actually see what's inside the directory. Similarly, `cp` also spits out an input/output error. The HDD seems otherwise fine - all other files are perfectly intact, it's just that one folder.

Is there any way I can potentially recover this data from this broken directory?

Comment: Do you have another computer that you can use to verify that the SD is corrupt, and its not some obscure system error?

Answer (score 0):

We're going to fsck (file system check) your hard disk, run SMART utilities, and bad block scan your hard disk for errors.

## Step #1

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

To check the file system on your NTFS HDD...

- boot into Windows
- open a admin command prompt window
- type `chkdsk /f d:` changing the "d" to the appropriate drive letter

## Step #2

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start the `Disks` application
- select the proper disk in the left pane
- go to the "hamburger" icon and select `SMART Data & Tests`
- review the failure data
- run the SMART tests
- quit `Disks`

## Step #3

- still in the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open `terminal`
- type `sudo e2fsck -c -k /dev/sda` # scan for bad blocks

  - **note**: changing "sda" to "sdb" or some other correct drive designator
- badblock scan will take a while
- observe any output indicating that it found {single|multiple} bad blocks
- if there are none, or only a few bad blocks, reboot and try Ubuntu again
- if there are many bad blocks, backup your data, replace your hard disk

Comment: `fsck` on NTFS doesn't actually check anything! It just removes the "dirty bit" from the file system.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto ah, I missed that. Thanks. I've made some minor updates.